# Creating new tasks with the Wrike API and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, rest

I'm having trouble creating new Wrike tasks using VB.net and the Wrike API. I however, am able to connect to Wrike to GET a list of folders so I know I'm able to successfully authenticate.

Link to task creation docs:
https://developers.wrike.com/documentation/api/methods/create-task

The only required field is "Title"

```
        Dim accessToken As String = API_Token
        Dim apiVersion As String = "v4"
        Dim ApiBaseUrl As String = "https://www.wrike.com"
        Dim folderID As String = "Some Folder ID Here"
        Dim address As String = ApiBaseUrl & "/api/" & apiVersion & "/folders/" & folderID & "/tasks"
        Dim result As String
        Dim task_str_ As String = "importance=Normal&description=Test task description&dates={""start"":""2019-07-24"",""due"":""2019-07-30""}&title=Task Created With VS&status=Active"
        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
            request.Method = "PUT"
            request.ContentType = "application/json"
            Using requestWriter2 As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
                requestWriter2.Write(task_str_)
            End Using
            Dim webResp As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using reader = New StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream)
                result = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            TextBox1.Text = (result)
        Catch ex As Exception
            TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString
        End Try
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Comment: The documentation says you do a POST, not a PUT for creating tasks.

Comment: Why `request.Method = "PUT"`?. The method is `POST`. Btw, remove that TryCast: `Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(address)`. The response should also be declared with a `Using` statement or disposed of after.

Comment: Yep, changed to POST and fixed my Dim request line, good catch. However I'm still getting (400) Bad Request.

Comment: You're not posting a JSON. [Wrike ApiClient for .Net](https://github.com/staviloglu/Taviloglu.Wrike.ApiClient)

Comment: The `HttpWebRequest.ContentLength` is also missing.

Comment: after adding/editing these

Answer (score 0):

Once I made the suggested changes, everything works good.

```
        Dim accessToken As String = API_Token
        Dim apiVersion As String = "v4"
        Dim ApiBaseUrl As String = "https://www.wrike.com"
        Dim folderID As String = "Some Folder ID Here"
        Dim address As String = ApiBaseUrl & "/api/" & apiVersion & "/folders/" & folderID & "/tasks"
        Dim result As String
        Dim task_str_ As String = "importance=Normal&description=Test task description&dates={""start"":""2019-07-24"",""due"":""2019-07-30""}&title=Task Created With VS&status=Active"
        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.ContentLength = task_str_.Length
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            Using requestWriter2 As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
                requestWriter2.Write(task_str_)
            End Using
            Dim webResp As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using reader = New StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream)
                result = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            TextBox1.Text = (result)
        Catch ex As Exception
            TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString
        End Try
```